# Flutter custom scrolling with dynamic list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

have a question about flutter's `CustomScrollView`

What I have now is:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: CustomScrollView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          sliver: SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              <Widget>[
                Card(),
                Card(),
                Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

*code was simplified as it's an example.

As you can see there are 2 `Cards()` and a `Container` with `ListView` inside. Both cards has fixed height, the container with list has dynamic height.
How it works now: as ListView grow up we can scroll to the bottom of the list. So normally both `Card` widgets became invisible because `List`'s elements take all the screen.

The idea is to force second `Card()` to be pinned to the top of the screen. So basically it's should be on it's own place, but with more and more scrolling it should be pinned to the top of the screen while I'm scrolling list more and more.
The question is how can I do something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want only the second card to be pinned to the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SliverPersistentHeader`, I prepared this sample for you:

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  sliver: SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                    (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text("index: $index"),
                      );
                    },
                    childCount: 3,
                  )),
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  pinned: true,
                  delegate: PersistentHeader("Card 1"),
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  pinned: true,
                  delegate: PersistentHeader("Card 2"),
                ),
                SliverPadding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  sliver: SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text("index: $index"),
                    );
                  })),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class PersistentHeader extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
      final String title;

      PersistentHeader(this.title);

      @override
      Widget build(
          BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 7.0,
            child: SizedBox(height: 100.0, child: Center(child: Text(title))),
          ),
        );
      }

      @override
      double get maxExtent => 100.0;

      @override
      double get minExtent => 100.0;

      @override
      bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

More info: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverPersistentHeader-class.html

Comment: thanks. That's work for me. Have one more question. What is the best way to transfer data between these objects? I mean between card 1, card 2 and list. Since they are currently in different classes.

Comment: I've tried to use it, but it isn't help. I mean: Inherited widget contains final Object. I'm modifying some fields of that final object from different places. The thing is I want changes of object fields to rebuild the whole tree of InheritedWidget. Where am I wrong? Is this InheritedWidget case?